# FME Server SOAP or REST

Tags: fme-form

I would like to use SOAP or REST with FME Server 2011. But for SOAP, Safe Software propose to send an email for more information.  Does anyone have experience with this API?

*Tools: Visual Studio 2010 / CSharp / Wpf*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work for Safe Software and I can tell you that REST interface for FME Server is likely going to be much easier to work with and better supported in the long run. Our REST API is better supported through documentation and examples (e.g see the [REST Playground here](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/FME-Server-REST-Playground) and the REST API documentation [here](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Documentation_del/FME-Server-Developer-Resources). The SOAP interface is pretty much undocumented as you discovered.

We use the SOAP interface for communication between FME Workbench and FME Server (when using the web connection), but we plan to phase this out and replace this communication with REST in the next release.

Hope this helps.